# Data disappear after segue to SecondViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Before I comment on my project, I'm new to Swift and trying hard to learn.

In my project, I have two view controllers and will be named as `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. These two View Controllers can be accessed via `Tab Bar Controller`.

In my `FirstViewController` users can add data (assuming an object of instance "A") and then segue to `SecondViewController` to display it on a chart. My users can head back to `FirstViewController` to add another data (now an object of instance "A" and "B"), and then segue to `SecondViewController` to display on chart.

However, when I checked my debugger, I noticed that segue "A" instance is working fine. When accessing `FirstViewController` again to segue "B" instance, my "A" instance disappear. I'm using `myObject.append(myInstance)` for my array, but somehow the previous instance disappear on second segue.

I even tried adding another array of my class object in `SecondViewController`, to purposely store the "segue-ed" data of both instance "A" and "B".

I'm very certain that my method of codes is correct, but I think it has something to do with the life cycle of segue.

Comment: Could you add your code into your question?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two UIViewController classes (VCA and VCB) used in two scenes (SceneA and SceneB)
You have two defined Segues: 
one that seques from SceneA to SceneB - which we will called SegueA2B 
one that seques from SceneB to SceneA - which we will called SegueB2A

if you are using push segues you will actually see the init functions in the UIViewController classes called when the segues occur

If you want the SceneA to not reinitialize when performing the SegueB2A then you need to use an unwind seque - google to get details on the unwind segue

Hope I understood your question and was of help
Mark Z. Kumler
http://www.pennyworth.com/blog

Comment: Isn't it possible to keep appending my array in VCA instead of passing the data between both controllers?